# Minikube: create isolated nodes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to create a Minikube cluster on a linux server with 48 cores.
By creating a multiple node cluster and each node having a 2 core CPUs config, it seems all 48 cores are shared between every node; not isolated or dedicated!
How can i create such multiple node cluster with dedicated resources?

[image]